# Is it possible to split a GraphQL query into separate react-query caches

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-query

I have been using React-Query for a project work and I absolutely love it (actually replaced redux with it since 99% of the state was just server state).

I have a question though that I'm not too sure about.

The project itself is a dashboard of widgets. A dashboard could potentially have 10+ widgets on it.

We are using a GraphQL api so it's possible (and ideal) to make a single api call when the dashboard loads with each dataset we need and pass the relevant data to each widget. Using react-query, this would be ONE query, so all widgets would be subscribed to this single query.

The issue is we want to add features such as 'refresh', 'filtering' and 'pagination' to each individual widget, which would involve api calls just for that one widget, but as the entire dashboard of widgets is subscribed to ONE query, the whole dashboard would refresh etc.

Is there a way to:-

- make a single graphql call on initial load to get potentially 10+
  sets of data for each widget
- have each widget be subscribed to their own individual dataset
  (separate query)

I have seen on the docs that we get access to the query client and could potentially use an onSuccess function to 'setQueryClient' to a selection of individual queries but I've read that this isn't a good approach and that 'setQueryClient' should only be used for optimistic updates.

Hopefully the above explanation makes sense, and any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make one request on the Dashboard for all widgets, and then render them. But instead of passing data down, I would make another `useQuery` inside each widget, which would only get data for that widget. You can prime the cache for that query with `initialData`, where you can pull out the data for that widget from the dashboard query. That way, you’ll get the data from the dashboard query for the first render (and no additional loading state), but each widget is still only subscribed to its own data. Don’t forget to set a small `staleTime`, or you’ll get an instant background refetch :)

Alternatively, the `select` option will also work well in terms of optimized re-renders, but there will always be the "big" request that fetches all the data for all widgets. If they all need to refresh at the same time, this is also a good option.